# (Basic) confusion about value of scalar-fermion vertex $\phi\psi_i\psi_j$ for Majorana fermions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, supersymmetry, neutrinos, majorana-fermions

If I have a toy model with $N$ Majorana fermions $\lbrace\psi_i\rbrace_{i=1,\ldots,N}$ and a scalar field $\phi$ where the interaction among the fields is

$$
\mathcal L_\text{int}= \sum_{i,j=1}^N
a_{ij}\phi\bar\psi_i\psi_j
$$

For example for $N=2$ it would be

$$
\mathcal L_\text{int}=
a_{11}\phi
\bar\psi_1\psi_1
+a_{12}\phi
\bar\psi_1\psi_2
+a_{21}\phi
\bar\psi_2\psi_1
+a_{22}\phi
\bar\psi_2\psi_2
$$
But for Majorana fermions one can demonstrate that $\bar\psi_i\psi_j=\bar\psi_j\psi_i$, so the term including the interaction $\phi\psi_1\psi_2$ is
$$
\mathcal L_\text{12}=
(a_{12}+a_{21})\phi
\bar\psi_1\psi_2
$$
I would think the respective vertices of the different interactions are
$$
\Gamma(\phi\psi_1\psi_1)=a_{11}
$$
$$
\Gamma(\phi\psi_1\psi_2)=a_{12}+a_{21}
$$
$$
\Gamma(\phi\psi_2\psi_2)=a_{22}
$$
But what I generally see is the vertex being
$$
\Gamma(\phi\psi_i\psi_j)=a_{ij}
$$
Which is different to my conclusion for $i\neq j$. For example, I see this in [Complete set of Feynman rules for the MSSM](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/9511250.pdf) in the interaction neutral Higgs-Neutralinos ($H^0\chi^0_i\chi^0_j$).

Whether the way I try to see the value of the vertex is wrong or it is wrong the reference about the vertex, I don't know which it is.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong about what I initially thought, the vertex is in fact

$$
\Gamma(\phi\psi_i\psi_j)=a_{ij}+a_{ji}
$$

for all $i,j$.

The way I saw it is with an example, consider the process $\phi+\psi_a\to\psi_b$. The way to deduce the vertex is calculating

$$
\Gamma(\phi\psi_a\psi_b)\to\sum_{i,j}\langle0|
b_b
\text{:}(a_{ij}\phi\bar\psi_i\psi_j)\text{:}
b_a^\dagger|0\rangle
$$

where $\text{:}(\cdots)\text{:}$ is normal ordering, $b_i^\dagger$ and $b_i$ are the creation and anhilition operators of the fermions respectively (ignoring dependencies like momentum or spin), they have anticommutation properties

$$
\lbrace
b_i,b_j
\rbrace=
\lbrace
b_i^\dagger,b_j^\dagger
\rbrace=0
,\quad
\lbrace
b_i,b_j^\dagger
\rbrace\sim\delta_{ij}
$$

For the sake of the argument we are going to ignore the integral, sum of spins and constants in the decomposition of the fermion fields in $b,b^\dagger$

$$
\psi_i\sim b_iu_i+b_i^\dagger v_i
$$
$$
\bar\psi_i\sim b_i\bar v_i+b_i^\dagger\bar u_i
$$
where $u,v$ are 4-component spinors representing the particle and antiparticle state. Also we are going to ignore the $\phi$ field, then we have the vertex is

$$
\Gamma(\phi\psi_a\psi_b)
\to\sum_{i,j}
a_{ij}
\langle0|
b_b
\text{:}(b_i\bar v_i +b_i^\dagger\bar u_i )
(b_j u_j +b_j^\dagger v_j )
\text{:}
b_a^\dagger|0\rangle
$$

Using $b|0\rangle=0$, $\langle0|b^\dagger=0$ and the anticommutation relations it is straightforward to see that
$$
\Gamma(\phi\psi_a\psi_b)
\to\sum_{i,j}
a_{ij}
\langle0|
b_b
\text{:}
(b_i^\dagger b_j\bar u_i u_j +b_ib_j^\dagger\bar v_i v_j)
\text{:}
b_a^\dagger|0\rangle
$$

Applying normal ordering

$$
\Gamma(\phi\psi_a\psi_b)
\to\sum_{i,j}
a_{ij}
\langle0|
b_b
(b_i^\dagger b_j\bar u_i u_j -b_j^\dagger b_i\bar v_i v_j)
b_a^\dagger|0\rangle
$$

Applying the anticonmutation rules and $\langle 0|0\rangle=1$

$$
\Gamma(\phi\psi_a\psi_b)
\to\sum_{i,j}
a_{ij}
(
\delta_{aj}\delta_{bi}\bar u_i u_j
-\delta_{ai}\delta_{bj}\bar v_i v_j
)
$$

$$
\Gamma(\phi\psi_a\psi_b)
\to
a_{ba}\bar u_b u_a
-a_{ab}\bar v_a v_b
$$

Using certain properties one can prove, at least in certain representations, that $\bar v_av_b=-\bar u_bu_a$ and then

$$
\Gamma(\phi\psi_a\psi_b)
\to
(a_{ab}+a_{ba})\bar u_b u_a
$$

For simplicity one can define $a_{ij}$ such that $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$, that implies directly that

$$
\Gamma(\phi\psi_a\psi_b)
=
2a_{ab}
$$

We see that the result is the same, regardless $a=b$ or $a\neq b$, also there's a number 2 present, which can be avoided redefining $a\to\frac12a$. I based this partially on the appendix D of [The search for supersymmetry: Probing physics beyond the standard model](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370157385900511?casa_token=xqFRYpzmuaoAAAAA:KZi284VYM3wPjBcAUUKG6hRtrPhLRwpaoZ6hVCRMHk5HU-b06IoOrODkKXIsmF9nk5FKJboVfIjY), where they explain things about the vertices in Majorana fermions.